# Apply User Defined Functions

Tags: r, apply

I have a user-defined function.

```
funct<-function(object,state){
  Init<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=length(object))
  colnames(Init)<-unique(object)
  Init[,which(colnames(Init)==state)]<-Init[,which(colnames(Init)==state)]+1
  return(Init)
}
```

Show the function output

```
letters1<-letters[1:5]
funct(letters1,"b")
```

I have a data frame, and apply my function on it to combine it by rows by using apply family.

```
dat<-data.frame(letters1=c("a","b"))
```

My try on it

```
mapply(funct,unique(dat$letters1),dat$letters1)
```

Desired output

```
rbind(funct(unique(dat$letters1),"a"),funct(unique(dat$letters1),"b"))
 a b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 0 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: found my solutions. `t(apply(dat,1,function(x) funct(unique(dat$letters1),x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Probably calling `diag` would be a more elegant solution to get the "desired output" :)

But you can also simplify your custom function a bit, e.g.:

```
> dat <- c("a", "b")
> sapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(dat == x))
     a b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 0 1
```

Comment: I have lookup list to create the matrix, e.g. there might be c ,d ,e that does not include in dat. but thanks tho.